# Solve the equation $\frac{1}{(\cos \theta)^2} = 2\sqrt{3}\tan\theta - 2$

Tags: trigonometry

> Assume that $0 < \theta < \pi$.  Solve the following equation for $\theta$. $$\frac{1}{(\cos \theta)^2} = 2\sqrt{3}\tan\theta - 2$$

[Question and Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoU8A.png)

Regarding to the attached image, that shows the question and the answer?

How could I solve this question and what are the steps to follow to reach the answer?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It seems that you got your answer so declare the thread closed or accept a answer

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be written as

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=$$

$$1+\tan^2(x)=2\sqrt{3}\tan(x)-2$$
or

$$\tan^2(x)-2\sqrt{3}\tan(x)+3=0$$

the reduced discriminant is

$$\delta=3-3=0$$

thus, there is one solution given by

$\tan(x)=\sqrt{3}$ which gives

$$x=\frac{\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: First, thank you for your answer and it clarifies the method to use for solving the problem.
But you converted 1/cos(x)^2 to 1+tan(x)^3. so could I consider that are equivalent, and if so what is the equivalent for  3/cos(x)^2

Comment: @MostafaSafwat not $tan(x)^3$ but $tan(x)^2$.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it by mistake

Comment: @MostafaSafwat is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Write $\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$ as $\sec^2(x)$ then look up Pythagorean identities. And possibly solutions to a quadratic equations.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both members by $\cos^2\theta$:

$$1=2\sqrt3\sin\theta\cos\theta-2\cos^2\theta=\sqrt3\sin2\theta-1-\cos2\theta.$$

Then

$$\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin2\theta-\frac12\cos2\theta=1,$$
$$\sin\left(2\theta-\frac\pi6\right)=1.$$